# How to read file content from git objects?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

**Having** a sparsely checked out working tree,
**I wish** to parse the full git objects,
**In order to** be able to update sparse `.git/info/sparse-checkout`,
based on some business logic (which should not be relevant here).

I tried to find a command to checkout "unsparsed" into a temporary folder.
I wonder, if I can probably even read contents out of git objects without a checkout.

Trying to build a module graphe around

```py
def _find_addons(dir):
    """ yield (addon_name, addon_dir, manifest) """
    for root, _, files in os.walk(dir):
        if ".git" in root:
            continue
        if any(s in root for s in SKIP_PATHS):
            continue
        if any(M in files for M in MANIFEST_NAMES):
            yield os.path.dirname(root), os.path.basename(root), _read_manifest(root)
```

Full code:

https://github.com/xoe-labs/odooup/blob/master/odooup/_modulegraph.py

Comment: Relevant command in git CLI to get an object from a blob (not sure how/if it would be useful for your needs in a python context, but still) is [cat-file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file), especially with `-p` flag. Just to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git cat-file -p <object name>` to print the content of a git object from its id.

Comment: Thanks great! did the job, together with `git ls-tree`: https://github.com/xoe-labs/odooup/blob/5cf008a08a68c3ae75a8434c7d1f602ef20b7750/odooup/_modulegraph.py#L16-L53

Comment: @Khoyo and how to get the <object name> from a file in the working tree?

Comment: @dani'SOlearnvaluenewbies' `git hash-object <file>` will give you the id that the current version of the file would have. But since git is content addressed, `git cat-file -p $(git hash-object <file>)` is equivalent to `cat <file>`, except it only works if git actually has the current version of the file in its datastore.